# Disabling the browser spell checker

Tags: firefox, browser

I have a DIV on my site that is marked contentEditable.  When it first loads it has some instructions pre-loaded that tell people what to do next. One of the words in the instructions is CTRL-A, which the browser spell checker doesn't find so it puts an annoying wavy red line under it.  I know there's a way to tell Firefox not to do spell checking but I can't set that in every browser that downloads the page.  I need is a way to flag that text, with some kind of tags around it, perhaps, that keeps the spell checker from worrying about it.

Is there a way to do that, that will hopefully work for all the browsers?

Thanks

Comment: [Controlling spell checking in HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms)

Comment: (The attribute described is [standardised](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-spellcheck), too.)

Comment: @millimoose: It works for Chrome, but Firefox seems to ignore it on `contenteditable` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/xhbSb/1/

Comment: @Blender I don't have FF to check, but does it also break when you set `spellcheck` on the same element as `contenteditable`? Because then it might just be incompatible inheritance rules.

Comment: @millimoose: Yep, that's what I tried originally.

Comment: @Blender Reading the spec, it would actually be buggy behaviour too. Weird. Time to open a bug in FF maybe?

Comment: @millimoose: Possibly. This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601431/spellcheck-false-on-contenteditable-elements